Gradle Convention plugins vs apply from project root dir
what are the reasons to use gradle convention plugin instead of using common gradle file apply from project root dir? is it faster or slower?
I can't find any reason to use the convention plugin except for a link to plugins instead of specifying the path to settings.

One big reason is the push to use Kotlin and statically typed build scripts.
